# Custom helper loading an image and that would work as a link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I have made this custom Html Helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper _helper, string _url, string _altText, object _htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("image");

    var path = _url.Split('?');

    string pathExtra = "";

    if (path.Length > 1)
    {
        pathExtra += "?" + path[1];
    }

    builder.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path[0]) + pathExtra);
    builder.Attributes.Add("alt", _altText);
    builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(_htmlAttributes));
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
}
```

I works exquisitely fine. And I must be honest, it is not my work, but I found it while browsing for help on stackoverflow.

That being said, I wondered it there's any way to transform this method so that it both loads an image AND works as an hyperlink, a clickable image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..
You just need to wrap your image into the anchor tag.
Please add appropriate href value using MergeAttribute method as you did for image.

```
public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper _helper, string _url, string _altText, object _htmlAttributes)
{
    TagBuilder builder = new TagBuilder("image");
    TagBuilder anchorabBuilder = new TagBuilder("a"); 

    var path = _url.Split('?');

    string pathExtra = "";

    if (path.Length > 1)
    {
        pathExtra += "?" + path[1];
    }

    builder.Attributes.Add("src", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(path[0]) + pathExtra);
    builder.Attributes.Add("alt", _altText);
    builder.MergeAttributes(new RouteValueDictionary(_htmlAttributes));
    anchorabBuilder.InnerHtml = builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing);
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(anchorabBuilder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok! could I do this using a string as a link, since I might want it to lead elsewhere in my app?

Comment: And I cannot write the `return anchorabBuilder.Create(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));` line because there's no "Create" symbol of methods in the anchorabBuilder tagbuilder